# p4python: get diff2 form depot

Tags: perforce, p4python

I want to retrieve output of the next command (where p4 is standard perforce client):

```
p4 diff2 //depot/...#1 //depot/...#2
```

In terminal it is producing something like this:

```
==== //depot/bin/build.sh#1 (xtext) - //depot/bin/build.sh#2 (xtext) ==== content
1a2
> #added something 2
9c10
< fi---
> fi
==== //depot/bin/README#1 - <none> ===
==== //depot/bin/status_ok#1 - <none> ===
```

Let's assume that I have next script in python:

```
from P4 import P4
p4 = P4()
p4.port = "1818"
p4.host = "localhost"
p4.user = "psih"
p4.client = "build_verificator_ws2"
p4.connect()
changes = p4.run_diff2("//depot/...#1", "//depot/...#2")
print changes
p4.disconnect()
```

After execution python script I will receive something like that:

```
[{'status': 'content', 'depotFile2': '//depot/bin/build.sh', 'rev': '1', 'rev2': '2', 'type': 'xtext', 'depotFile': '//depot/bin/build.sh', 'type2': 'xtext'}, {'status': 'left only', 'type': 'text', 'rev': '1', 'depotFile': '//depot/bin/README'}, {'status': 'left only', 'type': 'text', 'rev': '1', 'depotFile': '//depot/bin/status_ok'}]
```

List of files in depot with revisions but no diffs.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in using a non-tagged response:

```
changes = p4.run_diff2("//depot/...#1", "//depot/...#2", tagged=False)
```

Comment: I believe there is a known enhancement request to enhance the diff2 command to return the diff output in tagged mode. You might want to contact Perforce Technical Support and discuss this issue with them if that enhancement would be useful to you.