# Does Perforce have native diff python function returns Boolean type instead of diff list?

Tags: python, diff, perforce

As questioned, I'm surprised that I couldn't find any native diff function in P4Python module which returns a boolean other than diff list. Won't it be beneficial to have P4().is_identical(branch1, branch2)?

Does anyone know if there's already a method to do this? If there's really none, does anyone have any idea that how to parse the diff list to see the branches are identical completely?

The command I'm using `p4 diff2 //depot/temp_dev/boost/branch1/... //depot/temp_dev/boost/branch2/...`

The log is `==== //depot/temp_dev/boost/branch1/bbversion.h#7 (text) - //depot/temp_dev/boost/branch2/bbversion.h#7 (text) ==== identical
==== //depot/temp_dev/boost/branch1/ClientSpec.txt#1 (text) - //depot/temp_dev/boost/branch2/ClientSpec.txt#1 (text) ==== identical`

The python method I used is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663858/p4python-get-diff2-form-depot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `p4 diff2 -q -Od` or the Python equivalent.

`-Od` limits the output to differing files, and `-q` limits the output to only the headers, so if the two paths are completely identical you'll just get some kind of "no differing files" message that should be easy to check for.

Answer (score 1):

Sam got ahead of me, but I found a way to get over this in python as well programmatically. Just for interests if any:

```
def is_identical(branch1, branch2):
    command = ['p4', 'diff2', branch1, branch2]
    diff_list = _call(command).rstrip().split('\n')
    return False if False in map(lambda diff: ('identical' in diff), diff_list) else True
```

Compares to Sam's answer, this one loses in machine time.